# specific string replacements using linux commands

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have data in the following form:

```
<some text0>
<text1> <text2> .
<some text1>
<text3> <text4> .
```

Now I want to convert this data into the following form:

```
<text1> <text2> <some text0>.
<text3> <text4> <some text1>.
```

I know I can do it using C++, but is there some way of doing this using linux. I know sed is good at replacing characters...but I am not getting as to how should I use sed to do replacements of the above form.

Answer (score 2):

this one-liner works for your example:

```
kent$  awk '!/\.$/{s=$0;next}sub(/\.$/,s".")' f
<text1> <text2> <some text0>.
<text3> <text4> <some text1>.
```

explanation:

```
awk               #the program
!/\.$/{s=$0;next} #if the line was not ending with dot(.),
                  #assign it to s, read next line
sub(/\.$/,s".")   #we are here when the line ends with ".",
                  #then we replace ending "." with s, and print.
f                 #the input file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed "N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\) \.$/\2 \1./" YourFile
```

sed read 1 line at a time by default into a working buffer and print the content at end of process starting next line to process.

`N`  : add a \n to the buffer than load the next line of input

`s/Part1/Part2/` : take begining of the buffer until \n, the \n than everything until the . before the end($) and rewrite it in different order \1 \2 are respectively content of 1st and second group (a group is the content found matching element between ( and ) in first part of s/Part1/Part2/)

note that \ is used here mainly for escaping next char due to shell substitution between " " and . mean "dot"

Answer (score 0):

By redefining the record seperator with `gawk`:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print $1,$2,R $3}{R=RT}' RS='<some text[^>]>' file
<text1> <text2> <some text0>.
<text3> <text4> <some text1>.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use awk, but here's a long pipeline for contrast

```
sed 's/\.$//' <<END | tac | paste -d " " - - | tac | sed 's/$/./'
<some text0>
<text1> <text2> .
<some text1>
<text3> <text4> .
END    sed 's/\.$//' <<END | tac | paste -d " " - - | tac | sed 's/$/./'
<some text0>
<text1> <text2> .
<some text1>
<text3> <text4> .
END
```

```
<text1> <text2>  <some text0>.
<text3> <text4>  <some text1>.
```

Comment: See for yourself: execute it a bit at a time and see what it looks like: `sed 's/\.$//'  file` then `sed 's/\.$//' file | tac` then `sed 's/\.$//' file | tac | paste -d " " - - ` and so on. After that, read the manual pages: [`man tac`](http://man.cx/tac), [`man paste`](http://man.cx/paste), etc

Comment: An extra space is between `<text2>` and `<some text0>` compare to the request

Answer (score 0):

Simple and understandable `awk`

```
awk '{a=$0;getline;b=$NF;$NF="";print $0 a b}'
<text1> <text2> <some text0>.
<text3> <text4> <some text1>.
```

`a=$0` Store first line in variable `a`
`getline` Get the next line
`b=$NF` Store the last field in `b` (the `.`)
`$NF=""` Clear the last field
`print $0 a b` Print this line, previous line and `b` (the `.`)

Comment: I have read this several time. `getline is fine when used correctly`